# Android IllegalArgumentException - no view found for ID

Tags: java, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I am new to Android and am having issues with fragment navigation and instantiation from the action bar.
I have a MainActivity class and 2 fragments from the Basic activity template in Android Studio, which also implements a navigation graph. For each of the fragments I have an action icon in the action bar, like below:

[image]

The app's start destination is the first fragment. What I would like to happen is that when I click the second icon fragment2 would appear. The code I have for starting an instance of fragment2:

```
(...)
case R.id.action_steps: 

       Fragment stepsFragment=new StepsFragment();
                    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment_container, stepsFragment).commit();
       return true;
```

However, when I click on the second icon the app crashes:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0800cb (project:id/nav_host_fragment_container) for fragment StepsFragment{8238b37} (1bab8c06-d49e-4f22-a06e-cb0dc89b113f) id=0x7f0800cb}
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:315)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1356)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1434)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1497)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:447)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2169)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1992)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1947)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

1. How can I fix this?
2. Is it possible to "toggle" between the fragments by using the navigation controller (via the menu items in the action bar)? How can that be achieved (if possible, without losing state)?

Below xml for MainActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And content_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

PS: I have several classes and layouts and would be too much if I post everything at once, but please let me know if you need more info, thanks.

Comment: Share your xml for activity layout

Comment: @Steyrix, done.